# How to reconstitute a C# object from a ClrMd pointer

Tags: getvalue, clrmd

I am using ClrMd to examine memory in a C# app and successively created a runtime object on a process. 
I use the runtime object to call EnumerateObjects().  This returns a collection of ulongs that are references to all the objects on the heap.  If the reference is to a string, I have no problem reconstituting the string using the ClrType GetValue().  However, when I call GetValue() on a reference to other objects, GetValue returns what appears to be another reference (i.e. ulong).

Do I need to execute some kind of C# unsafe code?
[image: code sample]
By the way, I get the same result with EnumerateObjectAddresses() (is there a difference between the two?)

Comment: With that ulong, you can retrieve the type with `ClrHeap.GetObjectType`, and then retrieve the fields of that object, and so on

Comment: I did as you suggested, i.e. executed:  ClrType type2 = runtime.Heap.GetObjectType((ulong) myObject);     and the result was type2 = null.